# Page doesn't load if JavaScript file is missing

Tags: html, cdn

Im loading a javascript file from a CDN. Im developing locally and I noticed that when my internet went down and the remote file wasn't available, the entire page failed to load.

Is there a way of linking to a remote file, but making it so the rest of the page will load if this file is missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [asynchronous loading](http://friendlybit.com/js/lazy-loading-asyncronous-javascript/). That way unavailable files will not block loading the rest of the page but you could of course still encounter unexpected behavior if some necessary script files fail to load.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try placing the JavaScript file at the bottom of the page or use conditional includes.

```
if(Request.IsLocal)
{
    // Use local files
}
else
{
    // Use CDN files
}
```

Comment: Im only working locally during development. Once the site is live no requests to it will be local. Im most interested in best practice here, I know the Google CDN is unlikely to go down but id still like to have a backup in place, and I also may want to use less reliable CDNs. Thanks

Comment: I have been using the conditional includes because when working for instance with my laptop outdoors or at a remote site I may not have access to the internet thereby rendering my CDNs useless. Once deployed the conditional check  is negligible especially once you take caching into consideration.

Comment: You can try conditional include using #if DEBUG which will also work but not get compile into the assembly when building in Release mode, etc.

Comment: Sorry, but what does that do? Ive googled it quickly but didnt understand what I read. Thanks

Comment: Whenever your code is compiled in debug mode (the DEBUG symbol is created by the compiler when the application is run in debug mode) if will execute the code within the #if DEBUG ... #endif block, however when the code is compile in another mode, for instance release, then the code within the #if DEBUG ... #endif block is not compiled into the assembly.

Comment: @jdln: DaTribe is talking about server side code, looks like C#.